# what are the practical limits to ADHD treatment adoption?

Tags: adhd

Wikipedia says...

> People with ADHD may struggle more than others to sustain their
> attention on some tasks (such as schoolwork), but can maintain an
> unusually intense level of attention for tasks they find immediately
> rewarding or interesting.

Being able to attend to rewarding tasks more readily than presumably less rewarding tasks seems rational for everybody and all people are to varying degrees rational. (This would seem to suggest people who can devote attention to unrewarding tasks are irrational.)

Does this mean that everybody with jobs involving attention can stand to benefit from ADHD treatment substances if the financial cost is low enough?  I'm trying to understand the practical limits to ADHD treatment adoption.